# How to identify and delete duplicate rows, except for most recent

Tags: mysql

I'm working in HeidiSQL and I'm trying to figure out how to delete all duplicate rows except for the most recent. There are some slight differences amongst the "duplicates," but whenever more than four specific values are identical (i.e. UserID, ContactID, SMSID, and EventID) the row is considered a duplicate. I need to remove these according to the most recent row (identified by CreatedDate).

The following query identifies these rows:

```
SELECT a.UserID, a.ContactID, a.SMSID, a.EventID, CreatedDate
FROM WhenToText a 
JOIN (SELECT UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID
       FROM WhenToText 
       GROUP BY UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) b
ON a.UserID = b.UserID
AND a.ContactID = b.ContactID
AND a.SMSID = b.SMSID
AND a.EventID = b.EventID
ORDER BY UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID, CreatedDate DESC
```

However, I'm not sure how to delete these duplicates after I've identified them.

Here is some sample data:

[image]

Comment: When you say `"according to the most recent row"` do you mean that, in the case of duplicates, you want to _retain_ the record which is most recent?  Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I want to keep only the most recent duplicate. So I'm interested in the most recent CreatedDate. I've added a screenshot of some sample data in my original post. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
DELETE FROM WhenToText w1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID, MAX(CreatedDate) AS MaxDate
    FROM WhenToText
    GROUP BY UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID
) w2
    ON w1.UserID = w2.UserID AND w1.ContactID = w2.ContactID AND w1.SMSID = w2.SMSID
        AND w1.EventID = w2.EventID
        AND w1.CreatedDate != w2.MaxDate
```

This will delete any record for a given `(UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID)` group whose `CreatedDate` is not the most recent.  Keep in mind this may leave behind more than one record for each group in the event that the latest `CreatedDate` is shared.

If you want to test which this query first to see which records will be targeted for deletion, you can replace `DELETE FROM WhenToText w1` with `SELECT w1.* FROM WhenToText w1`.

Here is a link to a SQL Fiddle which demonstrates how the query will identify records for deletion:

[## SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ebf1/1)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using DELETE FROM JOIN, w/ a full demo with your data.

SQL:

```
-- Data preparation
create table WhenToText(UserID int, ContactID int, SMSID int, EventID int, CreatedDate datetime);
insert into WhenToText values
    (4,   25,  7934, 7407, '2016-02-10 00:00:11'),
    (4,   25,  7934, 7407, '2016-02-09 00:00:12'),
    (4,   29,  5132, 7407, '2016-02-10 00:00:11'),
    (4,   29,  5132, 7407, '2016-02-09 00:00:12'),
    (4,   31, 12944, 7405, '2016-02-10 07:03:02'),
    (4,   31, 12944, 7405, '2016-02-10 05:03:02'),
    (4,  146, 12908, 7405, '2016-02-10 06:52:02'),
    (4,  146, 12908, 7405, '2016-02-10 04:52:02'),
    (15,  63, 12964, 7401, '2016-02-10 03:42:04'),
    (15,  63, 12964, 7401, '2016-02-10 03:41:04'),
    (15,  64, 12326, 7401, '2016-02-07 03:01:03'),
    (15,  64, 12326, 7401, '2016-02-07 03:00:03');
SELECT * FROM WhenToText;

-- SQL needed
DELETE a FROM 
    WhenToText a INNER JOIN
    (
     SELECT UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID, MAX(CreatedDate) CreatedDate
     FROM WhenToText
     GROUP BY UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID
     ) b
    USING(UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID)
WHERE 
    a.CreatedDate != b.CreatedDate;

SELECT * FROM WhenToText;
```

Output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM WhenToText;
+--------+-----------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| UserID | ContactID | SMSID | EventID | CreatedDate         |
+--------+-----------+-------+---------+---------------------+
|      4 |        25 |  7934 |    7407 | 2016-02-10 00:00:11 |
|      4 |        25 |  7934 |    7407 | 2016-02-09 00:00:12 |
|      4 |        29 |  5132 |    7407 | 2016-02-10 00:00:11 |
|      4 |        29 |  5132 |    7407 | 2016-02-09 00:00:12 |
|      4 |        31 | 12944 |    7405 | 2016-02-10 07:03:02 |
|      4 |        31 | 12944 |    7405 | 2016-02-10 05:03:02 |
|      4 |       146 | 12908 |    7405 | 2016-02-10 06:52:02 |
|      4 |       146 | 12908 |    7405 | 2016-02-10 04:52:02 |
|     15 |        63 | 12964 |    7401 | 2016-02-10 03:42:04 |
|     15 |        63 | 12964 |    7401 | 2016-02-10 03:41:04 |
|     15 |        64 | 12326 |    7401 | 2016-02-07 03:01:03 |
|     15 |        64 | 12326 |    7401 | 2016-02-07 03:00:03 |
+--------+-----------+-------+---------+---------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> -- SQL needed
mysql> DELETE a FROM
    ->     WhenToText a INNER JOIN
    ->     (
    ->      SELECT UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID, MAX(CreatedDate) CreatedDate
    ->      FROM WhenToText
    ->      GROUP BY UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID
    ->      ) b
    ->     USING(UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID)
    -> WHERE
    ->     a.CreatedDate != b.CreatedDate;

SELECT * FQuery OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT * FROM WhenToText;
+--------+-----------+-------+---------+---------------------+
| UserID | ContactID | SMSID | EventID | CreatedDate         |
+--------+-----------+-------+---------+---------------------+
|      4 |        25 |  7934 |    7407 | 2016-02-10 00:00:11 |
|      4 |        29 |  5132 |    7407 | 2016-02-10 00:00:11 |
|      4 |        31 | 12944 |    7405 | 2016-02-10 07:03:02 |
|      4 |       146 | 12908 |    7405 | 2016-02-10 06:52:02 |
|     15 |        63 | 12964 |    7401 | 2016-02-10 03:42:04 |
|     15 |        64 | 12326 |    7401 | 2016-02-07 03:01:03 |
+--------+-----------+-------+---------+---------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This seems like a good approach. Is there a good way of testing this before executing it? I tried running it as a SELECT * FROM to try and get a return of all of the rows that would be deleted but couldn't get it to work. Any idea? Thanks again!

Comment: @David Updated the post according to ur new data. Pls try again.

Comment: Excellent, this works! Thanks for your help here, greatly appreciated. Just curious-- is there a way to automate the input of the table for CREATE TABLE or would does this have to be done manually? Ideally I would like to be able to query this directly in one step and avoid having to enter this manually.

Comment: I didn't get it. The output is just a demo. You just need to use the DELETE on your table.

Answer (score 0):

This should provide the solution you're looking for, given CreatedDate is a date datatype. This is also under the assumption that the most recent row is technically the most recent CreatedDate.

```
SELECT UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID, MAX(CreatedDate) AS CreatedDate
FROM WhenToText 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

With these values you could just overwrite WhenToText table...which would look something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_table LIKE WhenToText;

INSERT INTO tmp_table (SELECT UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID, MAX(CreatedDate) AS CreatedDate
                          FROM WhenToText 
                          GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4);

TRUNCATE WhenToText;

INSERT INTO WhenToText (SELECT * FROM tmp_table);

DROP TABLE tmp_table;
```

Comment: I just tried using this and it keeps saying that I can't "group on CreatedDate."

Comment: Also, I tried making some adjustments like replacing GROUP BY with ORDER BY and the query just returns 1 single row (i.e. the MAX(CreatedDate).

Comment: 1st Q: @David not sure how you're getting the GROUP BY error, as it's not explicitly grouping on that item. The 1,2,3,4 only refers to the items (UserID, ContactID, SMSID, EventID) if they're the first 4 items in the select statement. 2nd Q: You need the GROUP BY statement to run the aggregate MAX function correctly...throwing in the ORDER BY clause instead of GROUP BY messes with the aggregation and would simply return one row.